# Intellisense works on stack vector but not heap vector?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

When using Visual Studio 2012 if I create a vector on the stack I can then use intellisense to see which member functions are available. However, if I create the vector on the heap when I query the pointer I do not receive any member function suggestions.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Works for me: http://i.snag.gy/leNmt.jpg

Comment: maybe you can declare an expression like in gdb to point to a variable of interest in debugger

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I wasn't using the correct dereferencing operator. Thanks for your image- post as answer and i'll accept.